# For a spring enterprise web application with multiple instances, What is the way to retrieve the offset value from Kafka and store it?

Tags: spring, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm working on an enterprise web application that has a requirement to read from a Kafka system and then trigger events. Can anyone suggest a way to get the offset and also an ideal way to store the offset (Ideal way should be able to handle accessing by multiple instances of the application)?

**Note:-**
I'm using spring-kafka and open for any further suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear to me; typically only one instance will consume from a partition. Edit your question to provide much more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey Gary. I was looking for a way to store the offset value somewhere. Seems like after a bit of experimentation, I can see that the application works good now. But the thing is that, I have no clue where the last read offset is stored by consumer.

Comment: When I was writing the question first, I was planned to store that offset value manually into a database. That was one of the reasons for the confusion I was having too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent versions of Kafka, the offset is stored in a kafka topic. Kafka keeps track of the consumer offset for each partition in a topic `__consumer_offsets` which is a compacted topic; in other words; kafka itself keeps track of the offset for each consumer group.

With Spring for Apache Kafka; several options are provided for when the offset is committed.

In earlier versions of kafka offsets were often stored externally; it's now a lot simpler.

There may still be use cases for that but such scenarios are all supported by Spring Kafka; especially with the upcoming 2.0 release.

Comment: This is a nice thing to know. Thank you Sir. Can you also tell me what is the way to store offset externally, In case I come across an older version of the Kafka.

Comment: For older version of Kafka you need older version of Spring support for it. And that is Spring-Integration-Kafka 1.x https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka